# merge txt files with similar name

Tags: filenames, merge

I have thousands of `.txt` files in directory. Their names are:

```
ch14.ta_20452_206652_15-84.txt
ch14.ta_20452_206652_786-14.txt
ch14.ta_20452_206652_77-85.txt
ch14.ta_20452_206652_81-78.txt
ch2.ta_16903_17204-41-44.txt
ch2.ta_16903_17204-2-46.txt
ch2.ta_16903_17204-61-47.txt
ch2.ta_16903_17204-73-52.txt
```

I want to merge files with the similar beginning of the name (exp: `ch14.ta_20452_206652` or `ch2.ta_16903_17204`) into one txt.

Tried to do it manually with:

```
cat *ch14.ta_20452_206652* > ch14.ta_20452_206652.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope that helps:

```
for i in ch* ; do cat $i >> $(echo $i | sed 's/\(ch[0-9]*\.ta_[0-9]*_[0-9]*\).*/\1.txt/') ; done
```